# Are questions about philosophy education on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

We have many questions on the main site on the philosophy of education - pedagogical imperatives, ethics of student discipline, etc. These are fundamentally *philosophical* questions that happen to be about education. Are questions about *philosophy education* allowed?

Obviously, primarily opinion-based questions like "Should I major in philosophy?" or "Is Podunk University's Master of Science in Philosophy any good?" do not belong, but it should be possible to ask more objective or "good subjective" questions, such as the content of typical curricula, pedagogical best practices, structure of exam design, the knowledge, competencies or skills that can be expected from people with certain academic or professional qualifications in philosophy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect questions related to "pedagogical best practices, structure of exam design, the knowledge, competencies or skills that can be expected from people with certain academic or professional qualifications in philosophy" might be better asked on sites related to education, perhaps [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/). You may get more relevant answers there, but that all depends on who is actively answering questions.

If the "content of typical curricula" can fit the [reference-request tag](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) by being specific enough, it might be relevant to get interesting answers. You might want to read some of the questions and answers under that tag to see if this site is a good fit.

All that being said, what is allowed is what is not closed or deleted. I am sometimes surprised by what is and is not closed here.  However, even if a question is not closed, it does not mean that you will receive useful answers.